# Pass nonce, opaque params using Jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, api-testing, test-strategy

I'm absolutely new to `JMeter` tool, so the question may be incorrect.
I'm trying to send `API request`, which requires `Digest auth`.
I tried to use `HTTP Auth` manager, but it doesn't have all fields to set, like nonce or opaque. Is there any way to pass them in request using `JMeter` tools?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you are testing an API protected by [OAuth](https://oauth.net/) therefore:

- `nonce`: is basically a [`number used once`](https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/16/oauth-timestamps-and-nonces/) so my expectation is that it is a some form of a timestamp so you should be able to generate one using JMeter's [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)
- `opaque`: looking at [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

  > An opaque value used by the client to maintain
  > state between the request and callback.  The authorization
  > server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back
  > to the client.

  so you should get this `opaque` state value from the previous response.

Check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) for more information on bypassing OAuth login challenge in JMeter tests.